# Service Now: Uncaught ReferenceError: func is not defined

Tags: javascript, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I have an issue when I order/add to card on one catalog service item . In fact, I am using a custom 'Catalog Client Script' on the onSubmit action to control if the customer added or not a attachment. Please find below my client script:
[image: client script]

Script configuration:
[image: Script Configuration]

The error when I order/add to card:
[image: Error order]

I already targeted the cause, it's when I check the 'Applies on a Catalog Item view' (second image), but i need this to trigger the order and execute my script.

Do you know how to solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: can you please provide jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes, https://jsfiddle.net/n68f7gom/

Comment: There is no HTML file and I am not able to reproduce the issue in the fiddle.

Comment: Because i am using Service Now Modules, if you have one instance you will be able to add this script into catalogs items. Without Service Now it will be painful to reproduce this. I thought you wanted the javascript code to reproduce into your own SN. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: 'gel' is just a shortcut for " document.getElementById ", it's javascript function. But and unfortunately, to manipulate my form, i need to use GlideForm client-side API which provides methods for managing form. So I replaced:

`var cat_id = gel('sysparm_item_guid').value;`

by

`var cat_id = g_form.getValue('sysparm_item_guid');`

It works now.